# Telescope buying guide for a beginner in India

Tags: planet, telescope, asteroids, natural-satellites, space-debris

I am located in the southern part of India and am looking forward to buy a telescope to gaze up to look ay farther planets, moons in our solar system and take pictures. How should I go about getting a telescope as I know nothing about telescope and things I need to know?

Comment: Could you please describe conditions you'd like to observe the skies from? Saying you're from India doesn't really help, that's a large place. No need to name the exact location, but could you perchance note what levels of light pollution we're talking of (e.g. using [Bortle scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bortle_scale)), how high above sea-level you plan on observing from and what's your approximate budget? Also if you're willing to invest in used equipment, and what kind of photography equipment you already own? Thanks!

Comment: most of the time its cloudy and rainy but there are times of clear nights..

Comment: That's weather and yes, we all have it. What I meant is if you could please [edit] your question to include information regarding conditions when the skies are clear and observations would be possible. Please see the link for the [Bortle scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bortle_scale).

Comment: @TildalWave : 5.6–6.0 NELM and  920 metres (3,020 ft) above sea level.. my budget is under $850.

Answer (score 3):

If you are a beginning astronomer, there is not much point worrying about all the bells and whistles you can get with a good telescope.

Instead, the key points to look for are:

- light-gathering diameter - this gives an indication of how dim an object you will be able to see
- supports/stand/mount - a basic tripod will be fine if you want to see no further than Jupiter, but it will wobble too much for longer distance viewing, so a solid mount will be essential
- motor/computer drive - at high magnification, objects will pass the eyepiece very quickly, so you will want to look at tracking drives that can follow objects smoothly

But to be honest, you could start with a $100 telescope and really enjoy yourself learning the sky.

Comment: Could you please recommend me a good telescope for around $100 ?@RoryAlsop

Comment: I think the [Galileioscope](http://galileoscope.org) is a very nice piece of equipment. For the price, you get a nice scope, with good glass. Join an astronomy club, learn about the sky, for example by listening to [Astronomycast](http://www.astronomycast.com).

Answer (score 0):

Celestron 127slt is a great way to start and reasonable price for a beginner. 
It has star align system that it can guide you through the sky objects during the time zone you are in after you calibrate it.
It has also pretty good vision with its spectacular lens !

Answer (score 0):

Start off with binoculars like [Celestron Upclose 10x50](http://www.celestron.com/browse-shop/sport-optics/binoculars/upclose-g2-10x50-porro-binocular) available for around ₹2500 on [spacearcade.in](http://spacearcade.in/). You will also benefit from a tripod adaptor and tripod.

Then study astronomy on line or from a book .... In my opinion don't buy a scope ,instead make one yourself.

Comment: In future posts consider providing links to any websites and equipment you mention if possible.